# VueJs renaming properties in <template> doesn't rename them in <script>

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, rename, vuejs3

I'm using Vuejs3 with Intellij.

I would like to rename a property of my script that is used also in my template by simply using the "rename" command (shift+ F6).

For example, I have:

```
<template>
  <login" :user="user"></login>
</template>

<script>
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const user = User()

    return {user}

)}
</script>
```

When I try to rename the const "user" with the IDE "rename" command, it renames it only inside the script, but not inside the template.

Is there a way to configure the IDE to rename the properties everywhere?

Comment: Hi, have you tried this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#replace_search_string_in_project

Comment: Is "Search for text occurrences" enable in Rename dialog?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-44904](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44904), please follow it for updates